# yesno filter for variable assignment inside with tag inside blocktrans

Tags: django, templates

I'm trying to set a variable as follow :

```
 {% blocktrans with car_type=car.get_car_type_display article=(car.get_car_type_display=="XL"|yesno:'an,a') %}
```

but it doesn't work:

```
Could not parse some characters: |(car.get_car_type_display=="XL"||yesno:'an,a')
```

Could you please help me through this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the boolean comparison expression like that. You should make that comparison into a pseudo property on the model so you can do this:

```
 {% blocktrans with article=car.car_display_type_is_xl|yesno:'an,a' %}
```

Where your car model has the new method:

```
@property
def car_display_type_is_xl(self):
    return self.get_cart_type_display() == "XL"
```

Comment: Thanks, so it should  be like this  {% blocktrans with car_type=car.get_car_type_display article =car.car_display_type_is_xl|yesno:'an,a' %}

Comment: If it doesn't work, then the next thing to do is to create a model method that gets the an or a value and use that instead.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you